# Change default icons of zoom in & zoom out in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps API version 3 on my website, how do I change default icons of zoom in & zoom out in google maps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change the default UI controls on the maps api. However, what you can do is:

1. Remove the zoom controls from the map [see here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-simple)

   `var mapOptions = {
      zoomControl: false
   }`
2. Add custom controls [like this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom) and implement the zoom in and zoom out functionality on your custom controls (using the `setZoom(zoom:number)` function)